# Creating non persistent objects with SQLAlchemy: wrong employment of backref in a relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create objects of a given class Task, store some of them on the database employing SQLAlchemy, and discard the others. At the moment this class is created with:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hosts.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    host = relationship("Host", backref="tasks", cascade_backrefs=False)

def __init__(self, host, name):
    self.host = host
    self.name = name


class Host(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hosts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostname = Column(String)
```

When I perform

```
newTask1= GridTask(myHost, myName)
Session.add(newTask1)
Session.commit()

newTask2= GridTask(myHost, otherName)
Session.commit()
```

The first task is stored on the first commit -which is OK-  and the second one is stored on the second commit, what I want to avoid.

My question is, how can I declare Task and Host classes so a given instance is persisted on the DB only when explicitly asked for? I am correctly employing "cascade_backrefs"?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its the other way around (don't worry, I don't even know what direction to use until I just try a simple test):

```
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hosts.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    host = relationship("Host", backref=backref("tasks", cascade_backrefs=False))

    def __init__(self, host, name):
        self.host = host
        self.name = name
```

this is because the mechanism is:

1. new Task
2. Task.host = somehost
3. backref kicks in, has the effect of somehost.tasks.append(task)
4. its step #3 that makes "task" a child of "host" and therefore cascaded in
5. cascade_backrefs=False on tasks means, "if this event started with a backref (in this context "host" is the backref), don't run the save-update cascade.

Comment: You were absolutely right, thanks for your help. I have replaced the "host" relationship declaration by
    host = relationship("Host", cascade_backrefs=False)

and now a "task" object is only stored when it is added to the Session and commited.